# Fastest way to transpose 4x4 byte matrix

Tags: c++, c, optimization, matrix, bit-manipulation

I have a 4x4 block of bytes that I'd like to transpose using general purpose hardware. In other words, for bytes A-P, I'm looking for the most efficient (in terms of number of instructions) way to go from

```
A B C D
E F G H
I J K L
M N O P
```

to

```
A E I M
B F J N
C G K O
D H L P
```

We can assume that I have valid pointers pointing to `A`, `E`, `I`, and `M` in memory (such that reading 32-bits from A will get me the integer containing bytes `ABCD`).

This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737298/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-transpose-a-matrix-in-c) because of the restrictions on both size and data type. Each row of my matrix can fit into a 32-bit integer, and I'm looking for answers that can perform a transpose quickly using general purpose hardware, similar to the implementation of the SSE macro `_MM_TRANSPOSE4_PS`.

Comment: If you're trying to do this in C without writing to special-purpose vector instructions directly, I suspect the best is just doing it directly. The transpose only involves 6 swaps (12 byte reads and 12 byte writes) and they can be scheduled efficiently.

Comment: It would be useful to know why you need to do this - most matrix handling libs that I'm aware of rarely actually transpose a matrix, they just flag it as transposed and then access the (row,col) as (col,row) instead. No memory needs moving.

Comment: @RogerRowland When transposing a 16 *byte* matrix you may well find out that any transposition flags cost more on repeated access than the transposition itself.

Comment: Are these going to be numbers?Have you thought about using Eigen?

Comment: @Ben It is an array of *bytes*. They aren't *going* to be anything, they already *are*.

Comment: @KubaOber Yes indeed, that's why I'm curious to know more about the reasons behind the OP's question - with a large matrix, transposing can help performance via locality of reference, but as you say a very small matrix being frequently accessed via swapped indices may suffer overheads in other ways. I'd just like more background really ....

Comment: @KubaOber for many cases the flag can be a compile-time property. Assuming C++, the transpose function returns a new type called TransposedMatrix for which the element-access operators are mirrored.

Comment: @flodin Correct. This of course presupposed that such type can be used where it's being used.

Comment: @RogerRowland, one example of a useful byte transpose is transpose four pixels from RGBARGBARGBARGBA to RRRRGGGGBBBBAAAA.

Comment: @Zboson That's a good example - I hadn't thought of pixel formats in terms of matrices.

Comment: @RogerRowland, I used it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22244629/efficient-way-to-convert-from-premultiplied-float-rgba-to-8-bit-rgba/22249820#22249820.  Writing that answer I realized that the transpose could be done with one instruction: pshufb.

Comment: @Zboson Cool, and you just earned another upvote for that answer :-)

Comment: Do you accept vectorized solutions ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I'm looking for a solution that has the same constraints as Kuba Ober's. I'm not convinced that his solution is the fastest way to do this, but the more I think about it the more I'm beginning to think it may be. :(

Comment: Actually, these solutions are handling all the bytes separately, using 16 reads and 16 writes (or 12 in the in-place case). The portable arithmetic operations provide little to perform any kind of byte shuffling within or between registers (besides shifts).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let me rephrase your question: you're asking for a C- or C++-only solution that is *portable*. Then:

```
void transpose(uint32_t const in[4], uint32_t out[4]) {
  // A B C D    A E I M
  // E F G H    B F J N
  // I J K L    C G K O
  // M N O P    D H L P

  out[0] = in[0] & 0xFF000000U; // A . . .
  out[1] = in[1] & 0x00FF0000U; // . F . .
  out[2] = in[2] & 0x0000FF00U; // . . K .
  out[3] = in[3] & 0x000000FFU; // . . . P

  out[1] |= (in[0] <<  8) & 0xFF000000U; // B F . .
  out[2] |= (in[0] << 16) & 0xFF000000U; // C . K .
  out[3] |= (in[0] << 24);               // D . . P

  out[0] |= (in[1] >>  8) & 0x00FF0000U; // A E . .
  out[2] |= (in[1] <<  8) & 0x00FF0000U; // C G K .
  out[3] |= (in[1] << 16) & 0x00FF0000U; // D H . P

  out[0] |= (in[2] >> 16) & 0x0000FF00U; // A E I .
  out[1] |= (in[2] >>  8) & 0x0000FF00U; // B F J .
  out[3] |= (in[2] <<  8) & 0x0000FF00U; // D H L P

  out[0] |= (in[3] >> 24);               // A E I M
  out[1] |= (in[3] >>  8) & 0x000000FFU; // B F J N
  out[2] |= (in[3] <<  8) & 0x000000FFU; // C G K O
}
```

I don't see how it could be answered any other way, since then you'd be depending on a particular compiler compiling it in a particular way, etc.

Of course if those manipulations themselves can be somehow simplified, it'd help. So that's the only avenue of further pursuit here. Nothing stands out so far, but then it's been a long day for me.

So far, the cost is 12 shifts, 12 ORs, 16 ANDs. If the compiler and platform are any good, it can be done in 9 32 bit registers.

If the compiler is very sad, or the platform doesn't have a barrel shifter, then some casting could help extol the fact that the shifts and masks are just byte extractions:

```
void transpose(uint8_t const in[16], uint8_t out[16]) {
  // A B C D    A E I M
  // E F G H    B F J N
  // I J K L    C G K O
  // M N O P    D H L P

  out[0]  = in[0];  // A . . .
  out[1]  = in[4];  // A E . .
  out[2]  = in[8];  // A E I .
  out[3]  = in[12]; // A E I M
  out[4]  = in[1];  // B . . .
  out[5]  = in[5];  // B F . .
  out[6]  = in[9];  // B F J .
  out[7]  = in[13]; // B F J N
  out[8]  = in[2];  // C . . .
  out[9]  = in[6];  // C G . .
  out[10] = in[10]; // C G K .
  out[11] = in[14]; // C G K O
  out[12] = in[3];  // D . . .
  out[13] = in[7];  // D H . .
  out[14] = in[11]; // D H L .
  out[15] = in[15]; // D H L P
}
```

If you really want to shuffle it in-place, then the following would do.

```
void transpose(uint8_t m[16]) {
  std::swap(m[1], m[4]);
  std::swap(m[2], m[8]);
  std::swap(m[3], m[12]);
  std::swap(m[6], m[9]);
  std::swap(m[7], m[13]);
  std::swap(m[11], m[14]);
}
```

The byte-oriented versions may well produce *worse* code on modern platforms. Only a benchmark can tell.

Comment: +1 for teaching me a new word. I'd never heard of a [barrel shifter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrel_shifter) before (too stuck at the HLL stuff).

Comment: This can be done with one instruction with SSSE3: pshufb (ignoring the load and store).  See my answer.

Comment: @Zboson The question provides no platform, so to me, anything explicitly bound to one platform is outside the scope of the answer. It's still good to know, but I specifically didn't mean to invoke any platform-specific intrinsics.

Comment: @KubaOber, I understand.  Though I'm not sure my answer is out of the scope of the OPs question  The OP is asking for two things and he can't have them both.  You answered one of them (portability) and I wanted to show that the other (efficiency) can't be attained without violating the first one (12 shifts, 12 ORs, 16 ANDs is a lot worse than one shuffle).

Comment: The last two lines of your first code example are incorrect. You should be right shifting by 16 and 8 respectively.

Answer (score 13):

You want potability and efficiency.  Well you can't have it both ways.  You said you want to do this with the fewest number of instructions.  Well it's possible to do this with only one instruction with SSE3 using the pshufb instruction (see below) from the x86 instruction set.

Maybe ARM Neon has something equivalent.  If you want efficiency (and are sure that you need it) then learn the hardware.

The SSE equivalent of `_MM_TRANSPOSE4_PS` for bytes is to use `_mm_shuffle_epi8` (the intrinsic for pshufb) with a mask.  Define the mask outside of your main loop.

```
//use -msse3 with GCC or /arch:SSE2 with MSVC
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tmmintrin.h> //SSSE3
int main() {
    char x[] = {0,1,2,3, 4,5,6,7, 8,9,10,11, 12,13,15,16};
    __m128i mask = _mm_setr_epi8(0x0,0x04,0x08,0x0c, 0x01,0x05,0x09,0x0d, 0x02,0x06,0x0a,0x0e, 0x03,0x07,0x0b,0x0f);

    __m128i v = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)x);
    v = _mm_shuffle_epi8(v,mask);
    _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)x,v);
    for(int i=0; i<16; i++) printf("%d ", x[i]); printf("\n");
    //output: 0 4 8 12 1 5 9 13 2 6 10 15 3 7 11 16   
}
```

Comment: Using `_mm_lddqu_si128()` will perform better under certain circumstances, but never perform worse.  If `x[]` was 16-byte-aligned, then it could be even faster using `_mm_load_si128` and `_mm_store_si128`.

Comment: @St0fF, thanks! I had never heard of `_mm_lddqu_si128()` until now.  Interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the speed but these are okay.

```
template<typename T, std::size_t Size>
void Transpose(T (&Data)[Size][Size])
{
    for (int I = 0; I < Size; ++I)
    {
        for (int J = 0; J < I; ++J)
        {
            std::swap(Data[I][J], Data[J][I]);
        }
    }
}

template<typename T, std::size_t Size>
void Transpose(T (&Data)[Size * Size])
{
    for (int I = 0; I < Size; ++I)
    {
        for (int J = 0; J < I; ++J)
        {
            std::swap(Data[I * Size + J], Data[J * Size + I]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An efficient solution is possible on a 64 bits machine, if you accept that.
First shift the 32 bits integer constants by (0,) 1, 2 and 3 bytes respectively [3 shitfs]. Then mask out the unwanted bits and perform logical ORs [12 ANDs with a constant, 12 ORs]. Finally, shift back to 32 bits [3 shifts] and read out the 32 bits.

```
ABCD
EFGH
IJKL
MNOP

ABCD
 EFGH
  IJKL
   MNOP

A---
 E---
  I---
   MNOP
=======
AEIMNOP
AEIM

AB--
 -F--
  -J--
   -NOP
=======
ABFJNOP
BFJN

ABC-
 --G-
  --K-
   --OP
=======
ABCGKOP
CGKO

ABCD
 ---H
  ---L
   ---P
=======
ABCDHLP
DHLP
```

Answer (score 1):

I posted an answer for this same problem awhile back ago for SSE [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24599209/3100771).

The only things that need to be added are vectorized load/store operations.

This answer is similar to [Z boson's answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24819208/3100771). Examples for load/store can be seen there. This answer differs because in addition to the SSE3 implementation there is an SSE2 implementation which is guaranteed to run on any x64 processor.

It's worth noting that both of these solutions assume that the entire matrix is row major in memory, but OP's question states that each row could have it's own pointer which implies the array could be fragmented.